# Is CS50 AP available for new teachers for 2020-2021?

Tags: ap-cs-principles

I've taught AP CSP for a few years and am interested in teaching CS50 AP, but I'm having trouble getting started.   The links in the getting started guide at https://cs50.harvard.edu/ap/2020/ aren't working.
I've tried to email ap@cs50.harvard.edu, but no response yet.

Anybody have a suggestion?  Of course I can use the freely available material, but from a recorded workshop I watched there are tools for teachers that could be useful.

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se]!  For this question, I might recommend our sister site, [cs50.se] along with the tag `cs50ap`. There's no reason that your question is not topical here. It's a great question and a great fit for cseducators, but I see that it's gone 18 hours without an answer so I thought I might direct you to a place where you might get an answer faster. The other place to check would be in the teacher section on collegeboard.com.

Comment: I would humbly request to no mentions be made to `collegeboard.com` other than out of utmost necessity. No educator ever should be wishing for that pseudo-governmental behemoth to exist (nor any others like it). Yuck! I need to go wash my hands.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that CS50 AP has just come back to life at https://cs50.harvard.edu/ap/2021/ with new access information and so on, so I'm all set.